# Is it possible to write t-sql script to show all changes made to the database rows recently?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, monitoring

I'm learning a new product of my company and the database is `huge`.

What I'm doing is to learn feature by feature and through that to understand the codes and the associated database's data/functions/ect.

What I need: To see the change-set made to the database/data-rows recently, e.g. after I create a new user account, I want to see what are the new rows updated/created after I do that.

Is it possible? Please share if it is. Thank you!

Nam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set up a trace with the [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx). In the trace you can see what the client does when you create a new user.

Comment: Of course you would not in general want to run profiler on prod at all times (it can be a performance killer). So this is not a solution for an application. I'm aware the poster is just trying to learn the database, I just wanted the caveat for future people reading this.